# perl regex to php

Tags: php, regex, perl

```
%\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b%
```

how do i make this understood for PHP

i want to find all email addresses in an html doc

Comment: unrelated to the question, but wanted to point out that email addresses can include apostrophes in the name (eg John.O'Brien@gmail.com).

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports Perl regex through the `preg_replace` and `preg_match` functions. You don't need to change your regex at all.

Comment: `preg_match_all` will generate a list of all matches. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [adjusting your regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to capture more address.

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in parser.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in parser.php on line 15

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in parser.php on line 18
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b

Comment: @Dasa You have to put delimiters around it, like in Perl.  `preg_match('/your pattern/')`  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php